# Passing Boolean param in laravel via url

Tags: php, laravel, url

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29740218/7921383 handling Boolean values in URL is depend on framework.

How to pass Boolean values `false` and `true` in laravel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass boolean variable of false in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739970/how-to-pass-boolean-variable-of-false-in-a-url)

Comment: It depends .... see this URL : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29740034/3110023

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since version `laravel/framework: v6.13.`
There are added ability to call on the `\Illuminate\Http\Request` method `boolean`
that will return true when value is "1", "true", "on", and "yes". Otherwise, returns false.

Answer (score 6):

Via a URL you could pass `1`(as true) or `0`(as false) for boolean values.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this way:

```
http://some-url?arg=true
```

Or

```
http://some-url?arg=false
```

And in php:

```
$boolean = filter_var( $request->query('arg'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a helper in laravel

```php
Request::boolean('query-param-name')
```

At the end it does same thing as [Dimitri Leiko described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60073270/passing-boolean-param-in-laravel-via-url/60073536#60073536), but maybe helps other people.

```php
 public function boolean($key = null, $default = false)
    {
        return filter_var($this->input($key, $default), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
    }
```

Comment: I dislike it as using Facade is a bad thing
I 
https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/131t2k1/laravel_considered_harmful/